# UWP Unexpected exception while executing Bluetooth connection in Dark mode

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

In my UWP project I have added two dictionaries for light mode and dark mode

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="LightThemeDictionary.xaml" x:Key="Light"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="DarkThemeDictionary.xaml" x:Key="Dark"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

The UI elements are working fine in both light and dark mode. However, whenever the code is executing Bluetooth related code, after executing the App gives Debug error without identifying any line of code.

After saving the dmp file upon exception I get this information

> Exception Information : The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access.

> Exception Information : A trace trap or other single-instruction mechanism signaled that one instruction has been executed.

> App.InitializeComponent.AnonymousMethod__13_0(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) Line 53   C#
> Windows.UI.Xaml.dll![Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for Windows.UI.Xaml.dll] Unknown

Before implementing Dictionary the App was working fine. Also, after implementing Dictionary the code is working in Light mode only. In Dark mode its crashing but only for Bluetooth connection codes, UI elements are working fine. Why only giving exception in Dark Mode? What might be the issue?

Comment: Please share your app's target version and your system's os version. the better way is provide [mcve].

Comment: And please refer this code sample [line](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BluetoothLE/cs/Scenario2_Client.xaml.cs#L113), you need call connect method in the UI thread.